# Purescript Union of Rows

Tags: typeclass, purescript, row-polymorphism

I've been trying to develop a component system in Purescript, using a Component typeclass which specifies an eval function. The eval function for can be recursively called by a component for each sub-component of the component, in essence fetching the input's values.

As components may wish to use run-time values, a record is also passed into eval. My goal is for the rows in the Record argument of the top-level eval to be required to include all the rows of every sub-component. This is not too difficult for components which do not use any rows themselves, but their single sub-component does, as we can simply pass along the sub-components rows to the component's. This is shown in `evalIncrement`.

```
import Prelude ((+), one)
import Data.Symbol (class IsSymbol, SProxy(..))
import Record (get)
import Prim.Row (class Cons, class Union)

class Component a b c | a -> b where
  eval :: a -> Record c -> b

data Const a = Const a

instance evalConst :: Component (Const a) a r where
  eval (Const v) r = v

data Var (a::Symbol) (b::Type) = Var

instance evalVar :: 
  ( IsSymbol a
  , Cons a b r' r) => Component (Var a b) b r  where
  eval _ r = get (SProxy :: SProxy a) r

data Inc a = Inc a

instance evalInc :: 
  ( Component a Int r
  ) => Component (Inc a) Int r where
  eval (Inc a) r = (eval a r) + one
```

All of the above code works correctly. However, once I try to introduce a component which takes multiple input components and merges their rows, I cannot seem to get it to work. For example, when trying to use the `class Union` from `Prim.Row`:

```
data Add a b = Add a b

instance evalAdd :: 
  ( Component a Int r1
  , Component b Int r2
  , Union r1 r2 r3
  ) => Component (Add a b) Int r3 where
  eval (Add a b) r = (eval a r) + (eval b r)
```

The following error is produced:

```
  No type class instance was found for

    Processor.Component a3 
                        Int 
                        r35


while applying a function eval
  of type Component t0 t1 t2 => t0 -> { | t2 } -> t1
  to argument a
while inferring the type of eval a
in value declaration evalAdd

where a3 is a rigid type variable
      r35 is a rigid type variable
      t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
      t2 is an unknown type
```

In fact, even modifying the `evalInc` instance to use a dummy Union with an empty row produces a similar error, like so:

```
instance evalInc :: (Component a Int r, Union r () r1) 
                       => Component (Increment a) Int r1 where
```

Am I using Union incorrectly? Or do I need further functional dependencies for my class - I do not understand them very well.

I am using purs version 0.12.0

Comment: In the definition of `evalAdd.eval`, you have `r :: Record r3`, but the call `eval a r` would require that `r :: Record r1`, and similarly, the call `eval b r` would require that `r :: Record r2`. So you would get a type mismatch if it was a plain function, but since `eval` is overloaded, the compiler just says that there is no overload for `a` + `r3` or for `b` + `r3`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Do I have to construct a new record with only the rows the component requires, for each use of eval on components within evalAdd.eval? Can I not make use of open rows some how so that as long as the r1 is a subset of r3, then passing r3 will work?

Comment: @JosephYoung is it really necessary to use a row to store your values? You can use a `Map` whose keys are `String`s representing `Symbol`s (akin to `reflectSymbol`) and whose values have type `Value`. `Value` could have a different constructor for each kind of type you're going to store. I understand you'll lose polymorphism but you'll save on the type-level gymnastics... Alternatively you can see if the [purescript-variant](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/) package meets your needs.

Comment: @KartikSabharwal I've actually solved my problem using the original approach, but haven't had time to form a proper answer. I haven't worked on the project for a while but from what I remember, instead of using a union for the components of two inputs, I simply just used the same variable for each. So in essence replacing `r1 r2 r3` with `r` and removing the union constraint. This achieved the effect of requiring the component to need all the variables its inputs require at compile time at the type level

Comment: @JosephYoung thanks for sharing your solution! It would be great if you could post it as an answer eventually since this situation is a neat exercise in the use of type classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the instance for Var is already polymorphic (or technically open?) due to the use of Row.Cons, ie

```
eval (Var :: Var "a" Int) :: forall r. { "a" :: Int | r } -> Int
```

Then all we have to is use the same record for the left and right evaluation, and the type system can infer the combination of the two without requiring a union:

```
instance evalAdd :: 
  ( Component a Int r
  , Component b Int r
  ) => Component (Add a b) Int r where
  eval (Add a b) r = (eval a r) + (eval b r)
```

This is more obvious when not using typeclasses:

```
> f r = r.foo :: Int
> g r = r.bar :: Int
> :t f
forall r. { foo :: Int | r } -> Int
> :t g
forall r. { bar :: Int | r } -> Int
> fg r = (f r) + (g r)
> :t fg
forall r. { foo :: Int, bar :: Int | r } -> Int
```

I think the downside to this approach compared to @erisco's is that the open row must be in the definition of instances like Var, rather than in the definition of eval? It is also not enforced, so if a Component doesn't use open rows then a combinator such as Add no longer works.

The benefit is the lack of the requirement for the RProxies, unless they are not actually needed for eriscos implementation, I haven't checked.

Update:

I worked out a way of requiring eval instances to be closed, but it makes it quite ugly, making use of [pick](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record-extra/3.0.0/docs/Record.Extra#v:pick) from [purescript-record-extra](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record-extra).

I'm not really sure why this would be better over the above option, feels like I'm just re-implementing row polymorphism

```purescript
import Record.Extra (pick, class Keys)

...

instance evalVar :: 
  ( IsSymbol a
  , Row.Cons a b () r
  ) => Component (Var a b) b r where
  eval _ r = R.get (SProxy :: SProxy a) r

data Add a b = Add a b

evalp :: forall c b r r_sub r_sub_rl trash
   . Component c b r_sub
  => Row.Union r_sub trash r
  => RL.RowToList r_sub r_sub_rl
  => Keys r_sub_rl
  => c -> Record r -> b
evalp c r = eval c (pick r)

instance evalAdd :: 
  ( Component a Int r_a
  , Component b Int r_b
  , Row.Union r_a r_b r
  , Row.Nub r r_nub
  , Row.Union r_a trash_a r_nub
  , Row.Union r_b trash_b r_nub
  , RL.RowToList r_a r_a_rl
  , RL.RowToList r_b r_b_rl
  , Keys r_a_rl
  , Keys r_b_rl
  ) => Component (Add a b) Int r_nub where
  eval (Add a b) r = (evalp a r) + (evalp b r)

eval (Add (Var :: Var "a" Int) (Var :: Var "b" Int) ) :: { a :: Int , b :: Int } -> Int  
eval (Add (Var :: Var "a" Int) (Var :: Var "a" Int) ) :: { a :: Int } -> Int
```

Comment: Perhaps mine only works due to R.get, which seems to act strange, probably because of the unsafeGet

Comment: Writing a VarA with instance `Component VarA Int (a :: Int | r)` with `eval _ r = r.a` works fine actually

Answer (score 4):

`r ∷ r3` but it is being used where an `r1` and `r2` are required, so there is a type mismatch. A record `{a ∷ A, b ∷ B}` cannot be given where `{a ∷ A}` or `{b ∷ B}` or `{}` is expected. However, one can say this:

```
f ∷ ∀ s r. Row.Cons "a" A s r ⇒ Record r → A
f {a} = a
```

In words, `f` is a function polymorphic on any record containing a label `"a"` with type `A`. Similarly, you could change eval to:

```
eval ∷ ∀ s r. Row.Union c s r ⇒ a → Record r → b
```

In words, `eval` is polymorphic on any record which contains at least the fields of `c`. This introduces a type ambiguity which you will have to resolve with a proxy.

```
eval ∷ ∀ proxy s r. Row.Union c s r ⇒ proxy c → a → Record r → b
```

The eval instance of Add becomes:

```
instance evalAdd ∷
  ( Component a Int r1
  , Component b Int r2
  , Union r1 s1 r3
  , Union r2 s2 r3
  ) => Component (Add a b) Int r3 where
  eval _ (Add a b) r = eval (RProxy ∷ RProxy r1) a r + eval (RProxy ∷ RProxy r2) b r
```

From here, `r1` and `r2` become ambiguous because they're not determined from `r3` alone. With the given constraints, `s1` and `s2` would also have to be known. Possibly there is a functional dependency you could add. I am not sure what is appropriate because I am not sure what the objectives are of the program you are designing.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question (and other purescript questions I see). I have posted the approach I believe I ended up using (I never finished the project). Feel free to comment if something I have said is odd, I haven't worked with purescript for a while